# Rain dropping on balcony making noise -- how to fix?

Tags: rain

My awning is a little bit too short, causing rain to drop on my balcony railing.

[image]

I don't really care about aesthetics, just want an easy solution.

I can think of some options:

1. Bend the flashing from below with a stick so that it extends a little bit farther.
2. Tape some soft materials along the railing to cushion the rain drop. My concern here would be that the material will grow moldy over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some black open-cell foam taped down with black duck-tape should do the trick.

Open-cell foam should allow the water to drain reasonably well after the rain stops, and by finding black foam & tape, it'll blend in reasonably well. Of course, if you buy some extra foam, you can replace anything that's starting to look a little grotty over time.

Odds are really good that if you start bending the flashing, you'll only give the wind easier access to lift it, allowing water underneath and/or ripping it off if the wind is strong enough. Additionally, that seems to be an apartment building type of balcony, and if so, you probably shouldn't be making permanent alterations to a place you don't own. If, on the other hand, you own the place, consider lengthening the overhang to direct water past the railing or, even better, put up a gutter to collect the water and guide it down the building properly. If water just runs off a 2nd or 3rd story balcony (based on comparison to the house shown in the background), it'll quickly dig a trench in the ground below.

Comment: Really smart idea -- thank you! TIL about open cell vs closed cell foam.

I do own the place, but I'll try the foam trick first before extending the overhang.

Comment: Honestly, a gutter would be better than a longer overhang.

Comment: Pipe insulation or pool noodle?